# Android make view disappear by clicking outside of it

Tags: android, view, onclick, back

I have some views that I make visible upon a button press. I want them to disappear if I click outside of those views.

How would this be done on Android?

Also, I realize that the "back button" can also assist Android users with this - I might use that as a secondary way to close the views - but some of the tablets aren't even using a 'physical' back button anymore, it has been very de-emphasized.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An easy/stupid way:

- Create a dummy empty view (let's say ImageView with no source), make it fill parent
- If it is clicked, then do what you want to do.

You need to have the root tag in your XML file to be a RelativeLayout. It will contain two element: your dummy view (set its position to `align the Parent Top`). The other one is your original view containing the views and the button (this view might be a LinearLayout or whatever you make it. don't forget to set its position to `align the Parent Top`)

Hope this will help you, Good Luck !

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM! thank you :) I was skeptical if blank imageviews would be recognized

Comment: You could simply use View as the dummy view. They're a little lighter and just seeing it in an XML is a good reminder that it's not used as a visual element

Comment: @RD. Glad to hear that :) . I did tricks similar to this with the RelativeLayout. it is more than a flexible layout.

Comment: make the dummy view clickable too, otherwise it will get clicks from its behind view

Answer (score 39):

Find the view rectangle, and then detect whether the click event is outside the view.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect viewRect = new Rect();
    mTooltip.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);
    if (!viewRect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
        setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to use the touch event other place, try

```
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: Just to note, `dispatchTouchEvent()` is supposed to return a boolean, but you do not return anything in your example. Additionally, you do not define nor explain what `viewRect` is.

Comment: Thank you, CaptJak.

Comment: What is `mToolTip`?

Comment: mToolTip is the view which is clickable and thus you are comparing if the event lie outside the Rect

Comment: It could be better like this:

`@Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        mTooltip.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);
        if (!viewRect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
            setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }`

Answer (score 29):

This is an old question but I thought I'd give an answer that isn't based on `onTouch` events. As was suggested by RedLeader it's also possible to achieve this using focus events. I had a case where I needed to show and hide a bunch of buttons arranged in a custom popup, ie the buttons were all placed in the same `ViewGroup`. Some things you need to do to make this work:

1. The view group that you wish to hide needs to have `View.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` set. This can also be set in XML using `android:focusableintouchmode`.
2. Your view root, i.e. the root of your entire layout, probably some kind of Linear or Relative Layout, also needs to be able to be focusable as per #1 above
3. When the view group is shown you call `View.requestFocus()` to give it focus.
4. Your view group need to either override `View.onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)` or implement your own `OnFocusChangeListener` and use `View.setOnFocusChangeListener()`
5. When the user taps outside your view focus is transferred to either the view root (since you set it as focusable in #2) or to another view that inherently is focusable (`EditText` or similar)
6. When you detect focus loss using one of the methods in #4 you know that focus has be transferred to something outside your view group and you can hide it.

I guess this solution doesn't work in all scenarios, but it worked in my specific case and it sounds as if it could work for the OP as well.

Comment: tiny suggestion: setFocusableInTouchMode ensures setFocusable is set as well.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the documentation properly. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 17):

I've been looking for a way to close my view when touching outside and none of these methods fit my needs really well.  I did find a solution and will just post it here in case anyone is interested.

I have a base activity which pretty much all my activities extend.  In it I have:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (myViewIsVisible()){
            closeMyView();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

So if my view is visible it will just close, and if not it will behave like a normal touch event.  Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it seems to work for me.

Comment: what happens when your view is visible and you click on it? looks like it will close it anyway

Comment: Very helpful.  See the following to be able to determine whether the touch is inside the view which is to disappear when the click is outside it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700286/how-to-detect-a-motionevent-inside-dispatchtouchevent[link]

Comment: I'm with @Guillaume, isn't this essentially useless because you can never click your view?

Answer (score 4):

base on Kai Wang answer : i suggest first check visibility of Your view , base on my scenario when user clicked on fab myView become visible and then when user click outside myView disappears

```
  @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect viewRect = new Rect();
    myView.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);
    if (myView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && !viewRect.contains((int) ev.getRawX(), (int) ev.getRawY())) {
        goneAnim(myView);
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: what is goneAnim(myView);

Comment: @DragonFire for change vibibility of your view to gone , maybe you want do it with animaiton :)

Comment: Thnks  myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  instead of goneAnim(myView); since that is another function of yours.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the specific ability to not only remove a view when clicking outside it, but also allow the click to pass through to the activity normally. For example, I have a separate layout, notification_bar.xml, that I need to dynamically inflate and add to whatever the current activity is when needed.

If I create an overlay view the size of the screen to receive any clicks outside of the notification_bar view and remove both these views on a click, the parent view (the main view of the activity) has still not received any clicks, which means, when the notification_bar is visible, it takes two clicks to click a button (one to dismiss the notification_bar view, and one to click the button).

To solve this, you can just create your own DismissViewGroup that extends ViewGroup and overrides the following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if(parent != null && parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(this);
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

And then your dynamically added view will look a little like:

```
<com.example.DismissViewGroup android:id="@+id/touch_interceptor_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" ...
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/notification_bar_view" ...
```

This will allow you to interact with the view, and the moment you click outside the view, you both dismiss the view and interact normally with the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Implement `onTouchListener()`. Check that the coordinates of the touch are outside of the coordinates of your view.

There is probably some kind of way to do it with `onFocus()`, etc. - But I don't know it.

Comment: how do I determine what the X, Y coordinates of my view dynamically? Am I using pixels or the dip values that I created its size with

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Make a wrapper view by `Fragmelayout` which will cover your main layout.

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- This is your main layout-->
     </RelativeLayout>
    
            <View
                android:id="@+id/v_overlay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- This is the wrapper layout-->
            </View>
        </FrameLayout>
```

**Step 2:**  Now add logic in your java code like that -

```
         View viewOverlay = findViewById(R.id.v_overlay);
         View childView = findViewByID(R.id.childView);
         Button button = findViewByID(R.id.button);
    
         viewOverlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
    
          
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   // Make the wrapper view visible now after making the child view visible for handling the 
  // main visibility task. 
                       viewOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the view when click performs outside the view:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
      if (isMenuVisible) {
          if (!isWithinViewBounds(ev.rawX.toInt(), ev.rawY.toInt())) {
               hideYourView()
               return true
          }
      }
   return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

create a method to get the bounds(height & width) of your view, so when you click outside of your view it will hide the view and when click on the view will not hide:

```
private fun isWithinViewBounds(xPoint: Int, yPoint: Int): Boolean {
        val l = IntArray(2)
        llYourView.getLocationOnScreen(l)
        val x = l[0]
        val y = l[1]
        val w: Int = llYourView.width
        val h: Int = llYourView.height
        return !(xPoint < x || xPoint > x + w || yPoint < y || yPoint > y + h)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper layout that notifies us when a click occurred outside a given view:

```
class OutsideClickConstraintLayout(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

    private var viewOutsideClickListenerMap = mutableMapOf<View, () -> Unit>()

    fun setOnOutsideClickListenerForView(view: View, listener: () -> Unit) {
        viewOutsideClickListenerMap[view] = listener
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        viewOutsideClickListenerMap.forEach { (view, function) ->
            if (isMotionEventOutsideView(view, ev)) function.invoke()
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    private fun isMotionEventOutsideView(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val viewRectangle = Rect()
        view.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRectangle)
        return !viewRectangle.contains(motionEvent.rawX.toInt(), motionEvent.rawY.toInt())
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
....
        outsideClickContainerView.setOnOutsideClickListenerForView(someView) {
            // handle click outside someView
        }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created custom ViewGroup to display info box anchored to another view (popup balloon).
Child view is actual info box, BalloonView is fullscreen for absolute positioning of child, and intercepting touch.

```
public BalloonView(View anchor, View child) {
    super(anchor.getContext());
    //calculate popup position relative to anchor and do stuff
    init(...);
    //receive child via constructor, or inflate/create default one
    this.child = child;
    //this.child = inflate(...);
    //this.child = new SomeView(anchor.getContext());
    addView(child);
    //this way I don't need to create intermediate ViewGroup to hold my View
    //but it is fullscreen (good for dialogs and absolute positioning)
    //if you need relative positioning, see @iturki answer above 
    ((ViewGroup) anchor.getRootView()).addView(this);
}

private void dismiss() {
    ((ViewGroup) getParent()).removeView(this);
}
```

Handle clicks inside child:

```
child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //write your code here to handle clicks inside
    }
});
```

To dismiss my View by click outside WITHOUT delegating touch to underlying View:

```
BalloonView.this.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }
});
```

To dismiss my View by click outside WITH delegating touch to underlying View:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    dismiss();
    return false; //allows underlying View to handle touch
}
```

To dismiss on Back button pressed:

```
//do this in constructor to be able to intercept key
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
requestFocus();

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my solution which I think it could be useful if :

- you are able to add a custom ViewGroup as root layout
- also the view which you want to disappear can be a custom one.

First, we create a custom ViewGroup to intercept touch events:

```
class OutsideTouchDispatcherLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val rect = Rect()

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val x = ev.x.roundToInt()
            val y = ev.y.roundToInt()
            traverse { view ->
                if (view is OutsideTouchInterceptor) {
                    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)
                    val isOutside = rect.contains(x, y).not()
                    if (isOutside) {
                        view.interceptOutsideTouch(ev)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    interface OutsideTouchInterceptor {
        fun interceptOutsideTouch(ev: MotionEvent)
    }
}

fun ViewGroup.traverse(process: (View) -> Unit) {
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val child = getChildAt(i)
        process(child)
        if (child is ViewGroup) {
            child.traverse(process)
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, `OutsideTouchDispatcherLayout` intercepts touch events and informs each descendent view which implenets `OutsideTouchInterceptor` that some touch event occured outside of that view.

Here is how the descendent view could handle this event. Notice that it must implement `OutsideTouchInterceptor` interface:

```
class OutsideTouchInterceptorView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr),
    OutsideTouchDispatcherLayout.OutsideTouchInterceptor {

    override fun interceptOutsideTouch(ev: MotionEvent) {
        visibility = GONE
    }

}
```

Then you have outside touch detection easily just by a child-parent relation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.touchinterceptor.OutsideTouchDispatcherLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.example.touchinterceptor.OutsideTouchInterceptorView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#eee"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.example.touchinterceptor.OutsideTouchDispatcherLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to get your work done:

**Step 1:** Create an ID for the outside container of your element for which you want to generate a click outside event.

In my case, it is a Linear Layout for which I've given id as 'outsideContainer'

**Step 2:** Set an onTouchListener for that outside container which will simply act as a click outside event for your inner elements!

```
outsideContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                            // perform your intended action for click outside here
                                            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Clicked outside!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

thank @ituki for idea

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/search_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#80000000"
android:clickable="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:clickable="true" // not trigger
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" 
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    ...............

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

and java code

```
mContainer = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.search_container);
    mContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Log.d("aaaaa", "outsite");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

it's work when touch outside LinearLayout