# How to detect a MotionEvent inside dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, motionevent

I have made a FragmentActivity. Some Fragments include an `EditText`.

I would like, when the Soft Input Keyboard is up and a `MotionEvent` happens - **except the Event of clicking inside the EditText** - the Soft Input to hide. Until now I wrote this code in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext()
                                  .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(),
                                   InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

It seems to work. But when I click inside the EditText, it hides and it comes up again. I wouldn't like this to happen. In this case I want the Keyboard just to remain on the screen.

1. Is there any way to disable somehow the `dispatchTouchEvent()` when I click at an EditText inside of a Fragment?
2. Is there any way to detect the click event of an EditText inside of `dispatchTouchEvent()` and make a condition there, that disables the hiding of the soft input?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since dispatchTouchEvent() is the first method called when a touch happens on a screen , you need to find whether the touch falls within the bound of your edit text view.
You can get the touch point as,
int x = ev.getRawX();
int y = ev.getRawY();

method to check whether it falls within the bounds of editText

```
boolean isWithinEditTextBounds(int xPoint, int yPoint) {
    int[] l = new int[2];
    editText.getLocationOnScreen(l);
    int x = l[0];
    int y = l[1];
    int w = editText.getWidth();
    int h = editText.getHeight();

    if (xPoint< x || xPoint> x + w || yPoint< y || yPoint> y + h) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your onDispatchTouch() do.

```
if(isWithinEditTextBounds(ev.getRawX,ev.getRawY))
{
//dont hide keyboard
} else {
//hide keyboard
}
```

Comment: Is there another way without including getting raw points? For example, if the Object, that was clicked is an Instance of Edittext, do not hide the keyboard.

Comment: A touch event is interpreted by android as follows Activity.dispatchTouchEvent()  -> ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent->View.dispatchTouchEvent->View.onTouchListener.. so Activity.dispatchTouchevent() is always called first, after that only we can know about the view which received the touch event.