# How to get the X Y coordinates and pixel size of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, coordinates, pixel

Given a `TextView`, is it possible to know at runtime the X and Y coordinates of where it is drawn?
Is it also possible to know the size (width/length) in pixels?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are `getLeft()`, `getTop()`, `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` methods for a view, it works for textView too. for more information , see the following link...

`getLeft()` and `getTop()` will return you the starting x,y co-ordinates.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: This give me always value '0'. This can not helpful to me, can you help me? suggest any other solution plz.

Comment: @YogGuru, you could also try `getLocationInWindow`, `getLocationOnScreen`, because `getLeft` and `getTop` are relative to view parent.

Comment: @Stan Hey..!! It was my mistake i do try to get this in Oncreat method it always gives '0' but when i try to get in ontouch method it gives me value.

Comment: these return the position relative to the parent, not the absolute position.

Answer (score 4):

**Coordinates relative to parent**

```
int x = textView.getLeft();
int y = textView.getTop();
```

**Absolute coordinates**

```
int[] location = new int[2];
textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41649402/3681880) for more.

**Pixel size**

```
int width = textView.getWidth();
int height = textView.getHeight();
```

**Notes**

- If you are getting `(0,0)` it could be because you are getting the relative coordinates related to the parent layout (and it is sitting in the top left corner of the parent). It could also be because you are trying to get the coordinates before the view has been laid out (for example, in `onCreate()`).