# Android check for view at position

Tags: android, view, position

I have a button that create a text view at a coordinate in a relative layout, what I want to do is check to see if a text view is already created at that position so that i can create the text view somewhere else.

To sum it up, my question is how to check to see if another view is at location x and y?
Here is the creation code:

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   DragTextView textview = MainActivity.createTextView(context);
   textview.setX(getX()+getWidth()+30);
   textview.setY(getY()+getHeight()+30);
}
```

Comment: If you are always setting the position on your own, then keep a `List` or `HashMap` to keep track of positions of views. Then when drawing another view, check against this `List` or `HashMap` to see if there is already another view at that position..

Comment: Does Android have a build-in function for this kind of check? because manually checking the position and boundary of each view is quite a tedious task for me.

Answer (score 1):

this sample code may help you...

```
    int left = textView.getLeft();
    int right = textView.getRight();
    int top = textView.getTop();
    int bottom = textView.getBottom();
    Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    int x = 200;
    int y = 250;
    if(rect.contains(x, y)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "TextView occupied (200,250) position");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know of the Rect class, I think i'm going to use a for loop for all of the child in the relative layout and check each one's Rect to see if any of them intersect.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you. I get this solutions are providing the coordinate of views. Store this values in some Collection object and refer same before placing the view

[Getting View's coordinates relative to the root layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout)

[How to get screen cordinates corresponding to the whole screen, and not the View touched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832333/how-to-get-screen-cordinates-corresponding-to-the-whole-screen-and-not-the-view)

Comment: I think getX() and Y fits the purpose already since i need the coordinate according to the parent layout and not the screen, I'm using a 2d ScrollView, which means that the layout can extend much further than the screen (about 2000 in width and height)