# Android: Set reference coordinate values of the screen to (0.0)

Tags: android, screen, coordinates

When I display the coordinates of my finger on the screen (fullscreen), it gives (17.0,17.0) for upper-left  corner of the screen. Why is this so and how can I change it to (0,0)?

(Phone: Samsung GS4)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832431/2982225)

Comment: @Payeli: But in my case the screen is fullscreen so should not raw and relative coordinates be the same?