# Reading Layout size at application startup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I need to retrieve the height of `ScrollView` defined in a layout xml file during activity startup. Which is the best practice to implement this. I've tried placing the code inside `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`. All gives height as 0 at startup. 
Is there any methods like `onFinishInflate()` for actvities?

Here is my code:

```
myScroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
int height=myScroll.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Get a final reference to your ScrollView (to access in the onGlobalLayout() method). Next, Get the ViewTreeObserver from the ScrollView, and add an OnGlobalLayoutListener, overriding onGLobalLayout and get the measurements in this listener.

```
final ScrollView myScroll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.my_scroll);
ViewTreeObserver vto = myScroll.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)myScroll.getBackground();
        height = myScroll.getHeight();
        width=myScroll.getHeight();
        ViewTreeObserver obs = myScroll.getViewTreeObserver();
        obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

});
```

see more in this thread:

[How to retrieve the dimensions of a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142090/how-do-you-to-retrieve-dimensions-of-a-view-getheight-and-getwidth-always-r)

Comment: Thanks @Anup. Its working. But, `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` is deprecated. any alternatives??

Answer (score 1):

You need to query view bounds *after* the layout was performed. Suggested place is `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)`. See this question for more information: [How to get the absolute coordinates of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view/2226048)

Also, if you dare to extend your Layout class, e.g. make a subclass of `LinearLayout` etc., you can override it's onLayout() in this manner:

```
@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

    myScroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView01);
    int height=myScroll.getHeight();
}
```