# why the coordinates of a view is always Zero

Tags: java, android, rect

I created a simple example to know how can I get the coordinates of any given `view`. Below are my attempts, and they always display `0.0`. any idea why that happens?

Code:

```
private int [] tv1Location = new int[2];
private int [] tv2Location = new int[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Rect tv1Rect = new Rect();
    Rect tv2Rect = new Rect();

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

    tv1.getLocalVisibleRect(tv1Rect);
    tv1.getLocationOnScreen(tv1Location);

    tv2.getLocalVisibleRect(tv1Rect);
    tv2.getLocationOnScreen(tv2Location);


    tv1.setText("xCords: "+tv1.getX()+", yCords: "+tv1.getY());
    tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2.getX()+", yCords: "+tv2.getY());
    //tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2Location[0]+", yCords: "+tv2Location[1]);
    //tv1.setText("xCords: "+tv1Location[0]+", yCords: "+tv1Location[1]);
    //tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2Location[0]+", yCords: "+tv2Location[1]);
```

***Updated***

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
            tv1.getLocalVisibleRect(tv1Rect);
            tv1.getLocationOnScreen(tv1Location);

            tv2.getLocalVisibleRect(tv1Rect);
            tv2.getLocationOnScreen(tv2Location);

            //tv1.setText("xCords: "+tv1.getX()+", yCords: "+tv1.getY());
            //tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2.getX()+", yCords: "+tv2.getY());
            //tv1.setText("xCords: "+tv1Rect.centerX()+", yCords: "+tv1Rect.centerY());
            //tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2Rect.centerX()+", yCords: "+tv2Rect.centerY());
            //tv1.setText("xCords: "+tv1Location[0]+", yCords: "+tv1Location[1]);
            //tv2.setText("xCords: "+tv2Location[0]+", yCords: "+tv2Location[1]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put it in onStart instead of onCreate. The view isn't drawn yet in onCreate (or at least not guaranteed to be).

Comment: @zgc7009 unfortunately, the coordinates still zero. please have a look at the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `Views` are not visible yet. You shouldn't put code to check things like this in `onCreate()` because everything might not be drawn yet. There are several different ways to accomplish this. The best place may be in `onWindowFocusChanged`

The 
[docs say onWindowFocusChanged()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Qj5.png)

> This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user

So you know that the `Views` are laid out at this point. You could also post a `runnable` on the `View`s or use.

[Here is an answer that uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view) the listener [onGlobalLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener)) which could also work for what you need.

Comment: more than draw I would say *layout-ed* or *misured*

Comment: @blackbelt good point! I got hasty in my explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @codeMagic it is working now when i placed the code to be inside `onWindowFocusedChanged` but with different outputs from the the methods that displays the coordinates, any idea why? please see the updated answer

Comment: @blackbelt i di not get what you mean? sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @codeMagic please have a look at the updated answer. the commented out lines are giving me different coordinates, which ne should i use?

Comment: Depends on what you want but probably `getX()` and `getY()`

Answer (score 3):

`View`s are neither measured nor laid out at this point so instead do it like this:

```
textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
            textView.setText("xCords: "+textView.getX()+", yCords: "+textView.getY());
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure that onStart is called after the current run loop is finished?

Comment: @M-WaJeEh please have a look at the updated answer. the commented out lines are giving me different coordinates, which ne should i use?

Comment: Thats because they are supposed to give different values. `X` is different from `centerX` of a `View`'s bounds. I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use the `ViewTreeObserver`, it will fire a callback when the layout is rendered which means you can get views' location.

```
tv1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
   tv1.getLocalVisibleRect(tv1Rect);
});
```

In addition, you should remove the listener installed if you don't need it because the ViewTreeObserver holds a strong reference to your listener object.