# How to find the exact (x,y) position of a view if there is a notification bar in screen (and it could be on top of screen or below)?

Tags: android, android-view

I am using the `view.getLocationInWindow(positionVariable)` method, but the y position is giving some offset value, maybe because of the notification bar on the top. So I used an offset variable.

But the problem is, when I tested on another device, the notification bar was on the bottom. So my view translation didn't work well.

How to get the exact x,y position of a view independent of where the notification bar is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Answer (score 0):

Use view methods getTop() and getLeft().

Comment: getTop() and etc gives values taht are relatives to thier container(parents).