# How to get screen coordinates of view inside of keyboard accessory view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscreen

Basically, i have put accessory view on top of the keyborad, inside that view i have view, for which i need the the position, but relative to whole screen (like i am putting it on the whole screen) and not the superview?

I kinda tried it like this:,

[How to get the absolute coordinates of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view)

but to no avail.

Comment: Update your question with the actual code you tried to use and explain the problem with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a frame (`CGRect`) or a point (`CGPoint`) from its superview's coordinate system to another view's coordinate system. All these methods are instance methods of `UIView`

For example:

`let convertedRect = superview.convertRect(subview.frame, toView: anotherView)`

In your case, you might try something like this:

`let cRect = keyboardAccessoryView.convertRect(accessorySubview.frame, toView: self.view)`

Note that this will convert the subview (whose `frame` is in the keyboardAccessory's coordinate space) to the current viewController's view's coordinate system.

If you want it in terms of the entire screen, try this:

```
let coordinateSpace = UIScreen.mainScreen().coordinateSpace
kbAccessoryView.convertRect(subview.frame, toCoordinateSpace: coordinateSpace)
```