# Get bottom coordinates of ImageView?

Tags: java, android

In Android, suppose I have an ImageView:

```
ImageView imgView;

public void doSomething(){
   imgView.setRotation(30); 
   //How do I get the bottom right coordinates of this rotated ImageView now?
}
```

I want to get the bottom right-coordinates of the ImageView, how can I do that with Android and Java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Comment: but he needs the bottom right-coordinates