# Swap the position of two TextViews dynamically

Tags: java, android, textview

Id want the big number on the top to swap position and dimension with one of the ones in the bottom while pressing a button that will be placed over the big number. I actually have a Constraint Layout  and absolutly no idea on how to do it.

[Here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttsy1.png)

Comment: get both of the text location in screen and re-set them.  hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view