# How to get the x & Y coordinates of a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have placed an image view in my layout, now i need to know its x & y coordinates to draw some stuff over it dynamically.

[image]

I tried `imageView.getTop();` & `imageView.getY()`but they both return "0", but the image is not starting from "0" there is some margin from start and much margin from top.

Is there any other way to get this.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure view has had a chance to update, run your location request after the View's new layout has been calculated by using view.post:

```
view.post {
    val point = IntArray(2)
    view.getLocationOnScreen(point)
    val (x, y) = point
}
```

Values SHOULD no longer be 0 but i had bad experiences with huawei devices. Other way to get x and y coordinates is using viewTreeObserver

```
view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)      
                val point = IntArray(2)
                view.getLocationOnScreen(point)
                val (x, y) = point
            }
});
```

Possibly you experience some visual glitch with this approach

Answer (score 1):

Try with imageView.getLocationOnScreen(int[]) to get X and Y of a view relative to its parent/screen:

```
int[] positions = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(positions);
int x = positions[0];
int y = positions[1];
```