# How to fetch latitude and longitude of Android device in background using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, location, weather

I am designing an Android weather app using Kotlin. I want to get latitude and longitude of the device in background, then fetch weather data for that.

How can I implement an auto detecting latitude and longitude feature in Kotlin?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/location

Comment: I think this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a location is pretty boilerplate.  Here's a quick example that uses the last known location.

```
    const val REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 100

    fun getLocation(context: Context): Location? {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { requestPermissions(); return null }

        val mLocationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as? LocationManager ?: return null
        return mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(findProvider(mLocationManager) ?: "")
    }

    fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION) getWeather()
    }

    fun getWeather() {
        getLocation()?.let { fetchWeatherData(it.latitude, it.longitude) }
    }
```